# Rotate Image Icon On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Was wondering if someone can help me with this. I want to be able to click the text/icon, and on click, the + icon rotates 45 degrees to look like a x icon. Upon second click, the icon rotates back to look like a + icon, and so on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/d264kt2t/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="pointer">
CLICK ME<img src="http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/plus.png" class="coolImage">
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:#000;

}

.coolImage{
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
  margin-left:7px;
}

.pointer{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @milksham I have added below the cross-browser working sample. Click "Run code snippet" to try this

Comment: @theonlygusti He seems to be lazy to look at anyone's code. He accepted whoever updated his fiddle rather than accepting good answer and pressing up vote for all good answers. Very bad :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [updated your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/pggys0x9/) with this script:

```
var rotated = false;
$(".pointer").click(function() {
  if (!rotated) {
    $(this).find("img").css({
      "transform": "rotate(45deg)"
    });
  } else {
    $(this).find("img").css({
      "transform": "rotate(0deg)"
    });
  }
  // Toggle the flag
  rotated = !rotated;
});
```

**Notice** That I also added the jQuery lib in the external ressources".

Comment: I updated the Fiddle, if you need it to be cross-browser. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Succinct with a beautiful animation

Personally, I disliked Louys' overly verbose and uninteresting solution.

Here, with jQuery at our disposal we can create something so much more beautiful:

```
rotated = false;
$('.pointer').click(function(){
  elem = this;
  
  $({rotation: 225*rotated}).animate({rotation: 225*!rotated}, {
    duration: 500,
    step: function(now) {
      $(elem).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'});
    }
  });
  rotated=!rotated;
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5873sw9v/1/) or the snippet:

```js
i = 1;
$('.pointer').click(function(){
  elem = $(this).children("img")[0];
  
  $({rotation: 225*!i}).animate({rotation: 225*i}, {
    duration: 500,
    step: function(now) {
      $(elem).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'});
    }
  });
  i=!i;
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.coolImage{
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
  margin-left:7px;
}

.pointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div class="pointer">
CLICK ME<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgf0C.png" class="coolImage">
</div>

</div>
```

We [`jQuery#animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) a "fake" object to be able to generate the smooth animation. You can change the `duration` to something else if you want to speed or slow the animation.

`rotated` is used as a stand-in variable to provide the toggle functionality.

Please ask if further clarification is needed.

Comment: He seems to be lazy to look at anyone's code. He accepted whoever updated his fiddle rather than accepting good answer and pressing up vote for all good answers. Very bad :-(

Answer (score 1):

Define a rotated class in you css, then toggle the class on clicks, for example like:

```js
var pointers = document.getElementsByClassName('pointer');
for(var i = 0; i < pointers.length; i++){
 pointers[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.target.getElementsByClassName('coolImage')[0].classList.toggle('rotated');
  });
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.coolImage{
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
  margin-left:7px;
  transform:rotate(45)
}

.pointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="pointer">
CLICK ME<img src="http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/plus.png" class="coolImage">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would you possibly be able to show me a working example of this? I wouldn't know how to do it

Comment: Do you use jQuery? Or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I don't code in those languages. I believe jQuery

Comment: Updated the example to fit your needs. It now works for every container on the site with that structure (a pointer-div with that image in the container)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a cross-browser working example:

```js
function rotate() {
   var elm = document.getElementById('imgToRotate');
   var className = elm.className;
   if(className.indexOf('rotate') === -1) {
      elm.className = elm.className + ' rotate';
   } else {
      elm.className = elm.className.replace(' rotate', '');
   }
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.coolImage{
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
  margin-left:7px;
}

.pointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.rotate {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE9 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="pointer" onclick="rotate()">
CLICK ME<img src="http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/plus.png" class="coolImage" id="imgToRotate">
</div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/jcwg1h71/

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but this works only when you click the icon itself. I need it to work when either the icon or text is clicked. Can you send me a jsfiddle where it works that way?

Comment: I have edited this now. Refresh the page and you can see now by clicking both text and image.

Comment: Nice, takes a lot of effort to come up with a pure vanilla js solution. Very succinct as well, I approve.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code into the `<img>` tag:

```
onclick="this.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(' + 45 + 'deg)';"
```

Comment: Can you send this to me in a working jsfiddle? I need the icon to rotate whether the icon or text is clicked